# Nginx http2 - browser creates new connection even after a few seconds idle

Tags: nginx, http2, keep-alive

I have a NGINX server running with http2 that serves my REST API.

Works great for concurrent requests.

But if there is even just a few seconds between request then the browser creates a whole new connection including ssl handshake and all that just makes things feel slower.

Under http1.1 you could use a keepalive_timeout setting but i can't find the equivalent for http2.

How to make the server and client keep the connection for at least a minute?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - It looks like the reason was that my computer was low on memory.

Works perfectly after cleaning up some leaking processes.

Makes sense that you don't have many open connections if you are low on memory.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution to the issue of low memory causing problems with open connections.
To enhance the reproducibility of your solution for other users, could you please provide more detailed instructions on how to "clean up leaking processes" and check for low memory or low connections? This additional information will make it easier for others to replicate your success and address similar issues effectively.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).